# how to activate a form with a html input submit in jsp?

Tags: html, jsp, java-web-start

I am trying to activate a form with a html button of type submit, in php it works correctly with isset $ _POST [] but not in jsp.

this is my button and I tried this code that I made, but it doesn't work. My form is not shown in case I click and the value is true...

`<input type="submit" name="form2" value="formulariom">`

```
 <%! boolean dia;%> 
      <%
           
            if(request.getParameter("form2")!=null){
                dia=true; 
            }else{
                dia=false; 
            }
          
         if( dia == true){
                               
        %>
          <form action="Servletinsert">
            <input type="text" name="Criterio" required>
            <input type="submit" name="uno" value="Consultar">
          </form>
        <%
         }
         %>
```

I would appreciate someone to help me, I am a newbie. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Your button in the code is named uno, not form2-

Comment: Also PLEASE: `dia = request.getParameter("form2")!=null;`

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks for your answers, the first input called "form2" submit is only to show the form that is inside the if conditional, the submit called "one" is for another process. I am beginning to believe that it is not possible, because if I do the conditional without a submit input, in the execution it works, but not interactively.